# Raspberry Pi and ultrasonic distance sensor HC-SR04

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3b+, sensor

So I have my Raspberry Pi, I watched a YouTube tutorial on what to do. I copied absolutely everything, but still, it's not working. The wiring is surely correct as it is copied from the video and the code is also. I run the code and it says it's running, there are no issues, yet the distance sensor is not measuring the distance, or at least it isn't showing the result. I have absolutely no idea what to do, I rewired, got a new HC-SR04 sensor, and changed the power cable for the Pi.

https://github.com/makertut/raspberry-hc-sr04 <- code is in here.

The output is just 'Distance measurement in progress
Waiting for sensor to settle'

Comment: That code should have timeouts on the 'while GPIO.input(' loops. Post a clear photo of your wiring.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/dc2a4198ae07939c20c54fdf600affc9 Here is a link to the wiring, its a photo. Also I appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like one end of a resistor is plugged into row 8 of the board, connected to nothing.

Comment: Nope, it's all connected correctly, here is a picture. I took out the sensor for visibility sake. https://gyazo.com/d06c997ac9bce32b8b8d8160b1f07efb

Comment: That image has 2 resistors in row 2, Milliways image has resistors in rows 2 and 3.

Comment: I saw that after and I changed it, unfortunately no difference. Still the 'No echo received' error comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following wiring diagram:

[image]

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html?highlight=distance#distance-sensor

[image]

With the code from https://github.com/makertut/raspberry-hc-sr04 :
(NOTE: code requires TRIG and ECHO to be swapped to match circuit)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 24 
ECHO = 23

print "Distance Measurement In Progress"

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
try:
    while True:

        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
        print "Waiting For Sensor To Settle"
        time.sleep(2)

        GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

        while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
          pulse_start = time.time()

        while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
          pulse_end = time.time()

        pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

        distance = pulse_duration * 17150

        distance = round(distance, 2)

        print "Distance:",distance,"cm"

except KeyboardInterrupt: # If there is a KeyboardInterrupt (when you press ctrl+c), exit the program and cleanup
    print("Cleaning up!")
    gpio.cleanup()
```

I get the following response:

```
Distance: 10.39 cm
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Distance: 10.58 cm
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Distance: 12.47 cm
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Distance: 12.52 cm
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Distance: 13.7 cm
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Distance: 15.83 cm
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Distance: 15.51 cm
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Distance: 15.76 cm
```

Comment: I am genuinely speechless. I have no Idea what to do. My wires and connections look perfect, The code is the exact same as yours. What you have given me is what I have done. I am genuinely so grateful for your response. I really appreciate the effort you have put in to help me. When I run the code I just get 'Distance measurement in Progress. Waiting for sensor to settle' Here is a picture:  https://gyazo.com/88a4992857aeb5950c0099b265fe706d       Here are another 2: https://gyazo.com/ff58ef6a0c2dc1bc8f939bb96a45956c                      
https://gyazo.com/24f198c738b5d2bd8d886b3ee96e18fc

Comment: Are you using a 1K resistor between echo and GPIO23 and 2K resistor between GPIO23 and GND?

Comment: It is a 1k resistor at echo and 2.2k at gnd

Comment: CoderMike I really want to thank you, it is working, the resistors seemed to be incorrect, genuinely you are such a good person. Thank you so much for the devotion and help, really, I am so grateful!

Comment: Great, please mark the answer as correct if working.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking us to debug some random tutorial you found on the internet which you may or may not have followed correctly.

Try https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html?highlight=distance#distance-sensor

If this doesn't work you need to post details of your setup.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your feedback, I have done everything that is on that link, I am getting a warning when i run the code 'no echo received'. I Think it is a problem with the code, that diagram from the link you sent me is what is in front of me right now.